# Trying to animate a NSLayoutConstraint with Swift 3

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to animate a constraint but it seems to be effecting the entire view. Here is the code that I am using to animate the constraint.

```
@IBOutlet weak var personHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

func animateBackgroundHeight() {
print("animate")
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
    self.personHeight.constant = 19 // personHeight is the IBOutlet to the constraint
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

}

Everything in the view moves when the animation is going on but I'm not sure why. What I want to animate is the height of the view, but not effect the TextField or the button. Think of the GreyView as a background element of the TextField.

Here is a image to show you which constraint I am trying to animate (green one)

Pink box represents the parent view.
Grey Box is the view that I am trying to animate the height of.
The TextField and button are above the Grey Box object.

[image]

Comment: The problem is either (a) you have constraints between the animated view and the other views that move; (b) you have ambiguous constraints; or (c) you have some confusion regarding the constraints in place (e.g. scroll views are common source of confusion, a la [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)). But there's not enough here to diagnose the problem. And rather than providing more details, distill this down further to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with enough details that allow us to reproduce problem.

Comment: @Rob, gave the question an edit, I'm hoping its more concise.

Answer (score 0):

You may animate the wrong view after all 
so to be clear about your question 
if you have x view that nested in another view 
and want to animate only x view 
then you should 
make

```
self.x.layoutIfNeeded()
```

instead of

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```